# A button inside an $out table created to fetch an uploaded file from a database is not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress, button, syntax

The button is needed to open the files uploaded by customers via an admin account. All the code for the button was added into wp-functions.php and presented inside a table using $out. Below is a piece of code:

```
function allOrders() {
    require get_template_directory() . '/bd.php';
    
    if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
        $where = 'WHERE userid = '.$_SESSION['auth'];
    }
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_orders $where ORDER BY id DESC";
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
    if(!$sql) {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }
    $out = '';
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {   

    foreach(json_decode($res['status'], true) as $key => $value) {
        $status_key = $key;
        $status_val = $value;
    }
        if($res['filetype'] == 'file') {
            if(end(explode('.',$res['file'])) != 'pdf' ? $ftype = 'doc' : $ftype = 'pdf');
        } else {
            $ftype = $res['filetype'];
        }
        $out.= '<tr class="orders-table_td">';
            $out.= '<td class="order_num '.$ftype.'">'.__('[:fr]Commande[:en]Order').' #'.$res['number'].'</td>';
            $out.= '<td class="order_words">'.$res['cnt_word'].' '.__('[:fr]'.($res['filetype'] == 'file' ? 'mots' : 'minutes').'[:en]'.($res['filetype'] == 'file' ? 'words' : 'minutes').'').'</td>';
            $out.= '<td class="order_cost">'.$res['cost'].' '.__('[:fr]euros[:en]EUR').'</td>';
            $out.= '<td class="order_status"><span class="'.$status_key .'">'.$status_val.'</span></td>';
            if($status_key == 'o-draft' AND $_SESSION['auth'] != 1 ) {
                $out.= '<td class="order_btn"><span class="order_publish" id="order_publish" data-order="'.$res['id'].'">'.__('[:fr]Commander[:en]Place an order').'</span>'.($_SESSION['auth'] == 1 ? '<span class="delOrder" data-id="'.$res['id'].'" data-file="'.$res['file'].'" data-number="'.$res['number'].'"></span>' : '').'</td>';
            } else {
                $out.= '<td class="order_btn"><span class="order_open" data-order="'.$res['id'].'">'.__('[:fr]Aller à[:en]Go to order').'</span>'.($_SESSION['auth'] == 1 ? '<span class="delOrder del-icon" data-id="'.$res['id'].'" data-file="'.$res['file'].'" data-number="'.$res['number'].'"></span>' : '').'</td>';
            }
        $out.= '</tr>';
        
    }
    return $out;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_orderopen', 'orderopen');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_orderopen', 'orderopen');
function orderopen(){
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    require get_template_directory() . '/bd.php';
    
    $_SESSION['orderopen'] = $_POST['orderid'];
    
    if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
        $order_page = 'single-order';
    } else {
        $order_page = 'admin-order';
    }
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['orderopen'])) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'session' => 'done',
            'order-page' => $order_page
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'session' => 'error'
        ));
    }
}
```

Clicking on the button should initiate an orderopen function (2nd part of the code of the button) related to a particular orderid displayed as "id" inside the table, row by row, in the order the files are uploaded by customers. The first part of the code of the button refers to the "orderpublish" function set up earlier in the wp_functions.php with the following code at the end of it: `wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );}` .

So it is a button with a double function, and all I need is to add a piece of code like this one `if($status_key == 'o-attent' AND $_SESSION['auth'] != 1 )` into the code of the button or the "orderopen" function for the button to function after the status of an order has changed from "o-draft" to "o-attent" as a result of execution of the first condition. My attempts to add this condition failed as I am not sure about the correctness of syntax in this particular case. So the button either disappears or is not clickable at all. How can I fix it? Is it possible to use `echo '<script>location.href = "/single-order"</script>'` models here?

And I'm having a SQL syntax error `ORDER BY id DESC at line 1`. Changing it to `ORDER BY 'id' DESC` , `ORDER BY 'id' 'desc'` ,`ORDER BY 'iddesc'` returns the same error.

Comment: You could be mixing a lot of things up. First, you seem to be using SQL instead of MongoDB. Secondly, your `$out` seems to be a php variable rather than the [MongoDB $out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation operator. Currently, I don't see any relation to MongoDB.(at least from the code you provided now)

Comment: Is the javascript tag still needed? You don't seem to be using any javascript.

Comment: How about this one then: echo '<script>location.href = "/single-order"</script>';      ?